# How long does it take the neurotransmitters to diffuse accross the synaptic cleft?

Tags: neuroscience, neurotransmitter, action-potential, synapses, neuron

Neurotransmitters get from the pre-synaptic neuron to the receptors on the post-synaptic neuron by diffusion across the gap between these two (the synaptic cleft). My question is, how much time does it take the neurotransmitters to diffuse from the edge of the pre-synaptic neuron to the receptors on the other side?

I have seen different values online, ranging from 0.05 ms to 1 ms. Which one is true?

Comment: Would be helpful to cite some of the examples you see. I suspect they refer to different conditions and have different definitions.

Comment: @Bryan I just want to know the average value in a typical synapse, which should has a cleft nearly 20-40 nm wide.